# When does Branch and Bound exactly stop giving solutions for the bin packing problem

Tags: complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis, optimization, branch-and-bound

I wrote a branch and bound algorithm for the bin packing problem and now I would like to know when exactly it stops giving solutions in a polynomial time.

I have **N** items (each item **i** has a volume **Vi**) and each bin has a volume **V**.

I tested the output of the algorithm and the execution time while varying the number of items **N** , the total volume of items **Vtotal** and the bin's volume **V** too.

What I noticed is that the termination criterion of the B&B algorithm does not depend only on **N** , it also depends on **Vtotal** and **V** .

For instance, if I have:

**N** = **18**

**Vtotal** = **18**

**V** = **8**

The algorithm works fine and I get the output I want in a polynomial time (few milliseconds)

But , If I have :

**N** = **18**

**Vtotal** = **18**

**V** = **14**

I don't get an output.

same for this test instance:

**N** = **18**

**Vtotal** = **21**

**V** = **14**

(If **Vtotal** = **25** I get a solution in few milliseconds)

What I need to know is : Is there a way (for example, assemble the three parameters in one formula) to know when exactly I don't get a solution in a polynomial time?

Thank you

Comment: "polynomial time" is not the same as getting an output quickly.

Comment: "Is there a way to know when exactly I don't get a solution in a polynomial time?" -- probably not. Intuitively, this is the same level of insight you'd need to settel P?=NP.

Comment: @IanRingrose I understand , but time complexity and execution time are related right?

Comment: @Raphael Yes that's what I know, but my supervisor keeps telling me to search for the exact value! 
I have been testing instances for months now. 
I really don't know what to do.

Comment: What "value"? Maybe I don't understand the task correctly, but assuming I do: is your supervisor clear about the fact that they want you do characterise bin-packing instances that are hard (for your algorithm)?

Comment: @Raphael He wants me to find the value of the parameters ( **N** , **V** and **Vtotal** ) for which the algorithm stops giving outputs.

Comment: @Alri, first define "stops giving output", then write a program that takes N,V,Vtotal from the command line, and a 2nd program that runs it for different value of  N,V,Vtotal, killing the process if it take too long, and log the results.

Comment: PS, get a new supervisor!

Comment: @IanRingrose What I mean by "stops giving output" is : It takes the algorithm too long to give me the results (If I don't get the result in few seconds, I terminate the program)
I already wrote a Branch&Bound algorithm. I am testing it with different values of  N , V and Vtotal and I am saving the results of each execution. 
(I wish I can get a new one! )

Comment: @Alri There is no single such triple, and "stops giving outputs" is a nonsensical property for an algorithm that *always* computes an exact solution. A reasonable task would be, "find an instance for which the algorithm runs longer than one night on our server". *That* is a reasonable thing to ask. Hint: many items that fit into many bins only in one particular way. No, the $v_i$ are *not* unimportant!

Comment: @Raphael Just like I have explained, I meant by "stops giving output" ; I don't get the result in few seconds so I terminate the program. 
So there is no exact formula that gives me when the algorithm stops running for few seconds?
I mean by formula (for example) : if **Vtotal - (V / N) >= 1.7** then I get the result in few seconds . 
I hope you get what I mean.

Comment: As far as I know there are no published results for bin packing as there are for randomized 3-SAT where a simple clause-to-variable ratio can tell you what sort of hardness to expect with high probability.  If I were faced with your problem I'd tackle it empirically by generating lots of random bin packing instances, running my algorithm against it, graphing the runtimes against the instance parameters and see what the graphs tell me.

Comment: @KyleJones I understand. Then I will try creating graphs from the instances I tested so far. Thank you.